# NN: How can I evaluate on single instances, when the validation dataset contains multiple instances?

Tags: validation, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, cross-validation

I am using Keras and GroupKFold.

My dataset contains several entries that appear more than once. It makes sense to keep them in the training. But I think that keeping them in the validation is at best superfluous and at worst it introduces bias in the results.

How could I skip the multiple instances of such entries, and validate on only one of each?

Let me specify that I am cross-validating. So, I imagine that the solution might come down to some parameter in either model.evaluate or in the GroupKFold splitting. But I haven't figured this out yet.

Comment: Just remove duplicates manually

Comment: @leljot How can I remove the duplicates for testing while keeping them for training, all while applying k-folds?

Comment: why would you keep them for training? If you are afraid of **bias** in testing, the same applies to training, it is just a bias. It is quite non-standard what you propose (to have dulpicates removed only from testing inside k-fold) thus no such function exists.

Comment: @lejlot "If you are afraid of bias in testing, the same applies to training": No, not at all. Although their parameters are the same, these identical entries correspond to different instances of events, and they must be taken into account. But if they are kept for the evaluation, then they will just repeat the same result many times, chipping away at the evaluation of the actual predictive power. Anyway, I just found a way to do this very neatly, I'll add a reply later.

Comment: @lejlot (To use a random example, imagine that people who bought a green sweater on an online shop will tend to also buy a pair of blue slippers. If this happens repeatedly, then of course I want to keep it in the training. But, at the same time, doing my validation on multiple instances of buying green sweaters will not enhance my understanding of the model's predictive capability.)